# verify views which are cached - CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, caching, cakephp-1.3

I am using CakePHP 1.3 for an application. Now I am caching views as explained on http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Cache.html#caching-in-the-controller. 

but problem is I don't find any folder/file inside tmp folder where I can verify view has been cached. I am bit worried as I don't know whether I have done some mistake or what.

current tmp structure

```
    tmp
      cache
        models
        persistent
     logs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default views are cached in the following folder:

```
tmp
  cache
    views
```

If you don't have it, create it and ensure Cake has write permission on it

Comment: +1, @nlcO also check if you're using file-based caching. If your system is using memory-based caching (APC of Memcached), then no files will be written

Comment: Couple other notes:
 
1. If debug > 0, Cache may be disabled: http://mbe.ro/2011/09/27/a-few-tips-on-how-to-optimize-your-cakephp-website/

2. See app/config/core.php (or app/config/bootstrap.php) for your cache config setting: `Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));`

Comment: thanks all. All answers & comments were useful. Only small mistake I did was added slash after action name correct syntax which worked for me `var $cacheAction = array(
        'add' => '1 day',
        'edit' => '1 day',
        'index' => '1 day',
        'view' => '1 day',
    );`